# How do I make an array with a specified amount of chars?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, char

I have a number (**int**) which specifies how many things I want in an array.
I need to be able to make an array with a certain number of **chars** (doesn't
matter what char it is). Is there a way to do this with arrays or would I
need to use something different like lists?

Comment: Googling the answer would have been quicker than typing this question out.

Comment: `int n = 1234; char[] chars = new char[n]`. Seriously read a tutorial

Comment: @TimFreese I looked for one...

Comment: @ZacG You need to up your google skills https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20how%20to%20create%20an%20array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Range`, passing in the count of items you want and cast them all to `char`:

```
var charArray = Enumerable.Range(0, myCount).Select(t => (char)t).ToArray();
```

Comment: Good but Linq would be too far for the guy who probably dont know how to create array!

Comment: That is the fanciest way of writing `var charArray = new char[myCount]` that I've ever seen.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary i thought this answer was some kind of trolling